# How can I validate thanks.php as well as check.php?

Tags: php, security, post

I've been creating a contact form using PHP having the process from `index.php->check.php->thanks.php`
I use the POST method and trying to validate thanks.php as well as check.php, and want to certain that no one can send the "value" directly typed on developer tools, and transfer to thanks.php.

Goal: to validate thanks.php as well as check.php.

Could you help me, please?

The code are below:

**check.php↓**

```
<?php
    require_once("validation.php");

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "POST" && $post["button"] !== "input"){
        header("location: index.php");
    exit;
    }

    $post = $_POST;

    $errors = isValidation($post);

    if(!empty(array_filter($errors)) || $post["button"] === "return"){
        $post["flag"] = "input";
    }else{
        $post["flag"] = "confirm";
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($post["flag"] === "input") : ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="content">
                    Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?= isset($post["last_name"]) ? htmlentities($post["last_name"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") : ""?>">
                    <?php if(!empty($errors["last_name"])) : ?>
                    <p style="color: red;"><?php echo htmlentities($post["last_name"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

    <?php if($post["flag"] === "confirm") :?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="content">
                Name ：
                <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="<?= $post["last_name"] ?>">
                <p><?php echo htmlentities($post["last_name"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="content-button">
                <button type="submit" name="button" formaction= "" value="return" class="submit">Return</button>
                <button type="submit" name ="button" formaction= "thanks.php" value="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**validation.php↓**

```
<?php
function isValidation($post) :array{

    if(empty($post["last_name"])){
        $errorMessage["last_name"] = "※Name is required";
    }

       return $errorMessage;
    }
```

**thanks.php↓**

```
<?php
    require_once("validation.php");

    $post = $_POST;
    $errors = isValidation($post);

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "POST" || $post["button"] !== "submit"){
    header("location: index.php");
    }


    $email = isset($post['email']);
    $subject = "Thank you for your enquiry！\r\n";

    $message = "Mr./Ms.{$post["last_name"]} {$post["first_name"]}\r\n\r\n".
               "The inquiry below has been sent!\r\n".
               "Name： Mr./Ms. {$post["last_name"]}\r\n".

    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\n";


    mb_language("Japanese");
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    if(mb_send_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "successfully sent\n";
    }else{
        echo "fail to send";
    }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h1>Your enquiry has been sent！</h1>
            <div class="content">
            <p>Thank you very much!</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent people from using browser utilities like "developer tools". All HTML that the browser receives is client-side code, executed on the client's machine and is therefore modifiable by the client.

Perhaps you're asking the wrong question. The correct question might be "How to validate data sent by the client?"

Generally speaking, for every value that you receive you perform a server-side (PHP) check to see whether it fits inside your predetermined criteria, and make the check as strict as possible.
For example, if you're supposed to receive a date value, then your validation code should check whether the input is a valid date in the specific format that you expect. And then there's likely business logic that can be applied to tighten the criteria further, such as making sure that the date isn't 10 years ago as well.

Unfortunately, there's not much to validate about a person's name, as it legally could be absolutely anything, so you can only `trim()` the field and then check whether it's not empty.
For an email you can use `filter_var()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

I'd suggest adding a CAPTCHA to that form too though, otherwise you'll get a LOT of spam.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, that's right. What I want to do is to validate on my thanks.php after check.php, but I have no idea what to do as I'm a complete beginner to PHP. To be honest, there are much more categories like tel, address, email, and confirm email etc, and they are in my validation.php too returning errorMessage as array. Do you have any idea how I can validate to thank.php?